# Cairo library arguments format

Tags: assembly, x86, cairo

What is the format of the Cairo functions arguments. I mean especially the coordinates and color RGBA arguments.

I want to use it from assembly language, so the C/C++ types are not suitable.

Is it actually 32bit floating point format?

Also, if "double" is 64bit - then the next question about the calling convention - how in 32bit stack, 64bit arguments are passed?

Comment: Looks like a lot of them are `double` parameters, which are 64-bit floats.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen - I always though "double" means 32bit. :?

Comment: Nope, `float` is 32-bit. `double` is 64-bit.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen - So, I edited the question - how to push 64bit argument in 32bit stack. :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling conventions vary across different operating systems and different platforms. For example, x86 uses mostly stack-based arguments, whereas x86-64 uses mostly register-based arguments.

As for pushing a 64-bit value onto a 32-bit stack, you'll need to push the two halves separately - since x86 is little-endian with a push-down stack, you'll need to push the upper-32 bits first, followed by the lower-32 bits.

To be completely sure, though, you can always write a small C function that calls the library function in question, compile it to assembly, and see how it handles arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I can't write C/C++ programs (small or big) it is a matter of religion. That is why I am asking here.